# UISplitViewController preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction not working on iPhone iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I've added a UISPlitViewController to the Main.storyboard and try to change the `preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.5` property to make my master controller be the half screen instead of covering full screen, but it doesn't work at all. I've tried changing `maximumPrimaryColumnWidth` and `minimumPrimaryColumnWidth` but none of these seem to work. I wonder what am I missing for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently working on an app with `UISplitViewController` and `maximumPrimaryColumnWidth` seems to work fine for me.
Make sure you are setting the `delegate` for `UISplitViewController` like

```
self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
```

And then the primary column width as:

```
self.splitViewController.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 320; // set the width based on screen needs.
```